# EXIF Propertyitem for Tags?

Tags: vb.net, image, exif

I'm using the ExifTools code to read and update the EXIF for JPEGs in a VB.NET project I am developing. So far I've been successful with doing what I need to but I'm having difficulty with the last thing on my wishlist- the "Keywords" or "Tags" entry. The "Tags" property (as accessed by  file right-click->properties->Details and just below the rating stars) is populated with information but if I use the PropertyItem for Keywords (Value 40094) with the ExifTools GetPropertyValue() function, it returns nothing.

It's pretty obvious that the "Tags" entry under file properties is not the same thing as what EXIF defines as "Keywords" but I have not been able to figure out what the correct PropertyItem value to pass is.

Does anyone know?

THANK YOU!
Steve

Comment: From further digging, I have found the following:  http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/grl/storage.shtml  This appears to be what I need. The download has sample code and a DLL which needs to be added to your project.  I originally heard about his code from this posting which has a C# version based on his original code: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/msg/99a5dd5c80c084b5?q=%22structured+storage%22+c%23&start=10&hl=en&lr&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&rnum=17  I actually wanted to use that code (since it doesn't need a DLL) but I couldn't convert it back to VB.Net